# Unicode characters not showing up on mobile platforms

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, font-face, google-font-api

I am trying to show some [Ge'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_language) characters
that look like this

### ኣስፋ ድስፍድስፍ ድስፍድስፍድስ

using [google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) but
it is not working on some older Nokia S60 Phones. Like N91 for example.

#### CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidsansethiopic.css);

p.txt{
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Ethiopic', serif;
    font-size:30; 
    color:red; 
}
```

#### HTML

```
<p class='txt'>
    ኣስፋ ድስፍድስፍ ድስፍድስፍድስ
</p>
```

As you can see in this [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc7fy/) most browsers render it perfectly. But not most mobile phone. I am led to believe that I am not using the google fonts properly.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What browser? As far as I'm aware the built-in Nokia Browser has never supported font embedding. Given the dying nature of Symbian I would hardly call this 'most mobile phones' though.

Comment: @bobince I am using Nokia 5800 with Opera browser v7.1.3. It is not that old browser. This wouldn't bother me much, but the site is targeted to mobile user and almost 90% are going to use similar phones. Is there is way around this?

Comment: Presumably you mean Opera Mini. It's designed for limited devices and bandwidth, and has also never supported font embedding. See http://caniuse.com/fontface

Comment: @bobince Thanks. I guess that is why I couldn't see anything. Its also weirld, off all the mentioned browsers the one I was using is the only that does not work :) I guess I can take comfort in knowing, it will work for the vast majority of browsers. Because I assumed if it didn't work for me, it may not work for most.